# Rendering leaflet map in shiny with custom HTML template

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to write a shiny app with a custom HTML template. I'm currently adding a simple leaflet marker map. I can create the object and it renders both in:

The console and a standalone shiny app:

[image: Shiny app by itself]

But not when I create a custom HTML template, where I just see empty space where the post should go.

[This github repo](https://github.com/EduardoClark/SinDudas) includes the files needed to replicate (its very light weight). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce if you do not provide a basic example. In this file, it is stated how to create the ui: https://github.com/EduardoClark/SinDudas/blob/master/ui.R And in this document, you can read more about HTML templates in Shiny in general: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the {{headContent}} tag on the html head.